# is there a way to check where argument of a bash function is a string versus array and to iterate over such argument?

Tags: arrays, bash, function, arguments

This is the code I'm trying to write, first, I do not know how to check given argument is an array, so I just wrote a crude regex.

```
function my_func {
  for arg in "$@"; do
    if [[ $arg =~ '\[@\]' ]]; then
      for item in "${arg[@]}"; do
        echo $item
      done
    else
      echo $arg
    fi
  done
}

arr=(one two three)
var="some plain text"
my_func "$var" arr[@]
```

Second, it outputs:

```
some plain text
arr[@]
```

But my intent is:

```
some plain text
one
two
three
```

Comment: Can you just pass each element as a separate string with  `my_func "$var" "${arr[@]}"`?

Comment: Yes, it works :), but I wonder is there a way to immunize function for this inconsistency.

Comment: Which inconsistency?

Comment: The ability to pass an array "by reference" (as it were) by using the `arr[@]` string as an argument and using indirection is a bit of a hack (and only works with global variables). You could try to check a string argument for `[@]` or `[*]` but those are valid in normal strings too. You could try adding a "is set" check to that name to get a secondary check on it being a variable but unless you have reason to accept this (in which case you should probably just assume you get one) I would say you shouldn't bother worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you want to pass by reference

```
function my_func {  
  for alpha
  do
    bravo="$alpha[@]"
    printf '%s\n' "${!bravo}"
  done
}
var='some plain text'
arr=(one two three)
my_func var arr
```

This works if you want to pass by value

```
function my_func {
  printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
var='some plain text'
arr=(one two three)
my_func "$var" "${arr[@]}"
```